# split values of a dictionary into seperate panda dataframe columns -- make them dummy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

Let's say we have a dataframe in this format:

```
id  properties
0   {"cat1":["p1","p2","p4"],"cat2":["p5", "p6"]}
1   {"cat1":["p3"],"cat2":["p7"]}
```

How can we convert it to this format?

```
id  p1    p2    p3    p4    p5    p6    p7
0   True  True  False True  True  True  False
1   False False True  False False False True
```

Keep in mind that the type of values in each cell is string.
It has just two categories: cat1 and cat2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set_index to `id`. As you said each cell is a string, so you need to convert `df.properties` from string of dict to dict by using `ast.literal_eval`. Next,  and using `str` method to get `cat1` and `cat2` and combine their lists and `explode` them to rows and assign result to `s`. Finally, call `pd.get_dummies` on `s` with option `dtype=bool` and call `max` on level=0

```
import ast

df1 = df.set_index('id')
df1.properties = df1.properties.map(ast.literal_eval)
s = (df1.properties.str['cat1'] + df1.properties.str['cat2']).explode()
pd.get_dummies(s, dtype=bool).max(level=0)

Out[1035]:
       p1     p2     p3     p4     p5     p6     p7
id
0   True   True   False  True   True   True   False
1   False  False  True   False  False  False  True
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

```
from itertools import chain

df.properties.apply(lambda s: ','.join(chain.from_iterable(s.values())))\
             .str.get_dummies(sep=',')\
             .astype(bool)
```

---

```
      p1     p2     p3     p4     p5     p6     p7
0   True   True  False   True   True   True  False
1  False  False   True  False  False  False   True
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `stack` + `explode` + `get_dummies`

```
u = pd.DataFrame(df['properties'].tolist())

u.stack().explode().add(',').sum(level=0).str.get_dummies(',')
```

```
   p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7
0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 2):

I will use `get_dummies`

```
df.properties.map(lambda x : ','.join(sum(x.values(),[]))).str.get_dummies(',').astype(bool)
      p1     p2     p3     p4     p5     p6     p7
0   True   True  False   True   True   True  False
1  False  False   True  False  False  False   True
```